# Is it possible to enable touch events for a View inside a ViewGroup but outside its bounds?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-linearlayout, android-viewgroup

I'm currently trying to design a ViewGroup (specifically a subclass of FrameLayout) that can layout any number of subviews and enable them for drag/drop *outside* the layout group. It's almost identical to a LinearLayout:
[image: View(s) inside a FrameLayout subclass inside a RelativeLayout]

Curently I am able to drag the views outside the ViewGroup and draw them, however after letting go of the view it can't be re-selected and further dragged around.
[image]

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this in a way that isolates the logic to the Layout subclass and doesn't involve needing to do much/any extra stuff in consuming fragments/view groups.

I've tried overriding `getHitRect(Rect)` in my FrameLayout subclass but it never seems to be called. `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` is of course not called either, presumably because the parent ViewGroup has decided not to deliver the touch to it because it was outside the bounds. I've tried implementing a TouchDelegate as well, but I think that needs to be set on the parent view, which means needing to know about this and doing this additional step when using this Layout.

Any ideas on if/how this is possible? On iOS it can be implemented fairly easily by overriding `hitTest:` to take into account the frames of the child views. Is there a similar method like this on Android?

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Without any code it is very hard to see what you are doing, but best guess would be that each view should a child view of the relative layout.